# A simple perceptron in Python

Tags: python, linear-regression, perceptron

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Example

My question is, why are there 3 input values in each vector when NAND only takes 2 parameters and returns 1:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke#Definition

Pasted code for your convenience:

```
th = 0.1
learning_rate = 0.1
weights = [0, 0, 0]
training_set = [((1, 0, 0), 1), ((1, 0, 1), 1), ((1, 1, 0), 1), ((1, 1, 1), 0)]

def sum_function(values):
    return sum(value * weights[index] for index, value in enumerate(values))

while True:
    print '-' * 60
    error_count = 0
    for input_vector, desired_output in training_set:
        print weights
        result = 1 if sum_function(input_vector) > th else 0
        error = desired_output - result
        if error != 0:
            error_count += 1
            for index, value in enumerate(input_vector):
                weights[index] += learning_rate * error * value
    if error_count == 0:
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you need one value that is a constant input. - also known as a bias.

If you notice you have three weights as well, so the first item in the triple ( which seems to always be 1 ) should be seen as 'input 0', (the bias). This is a constant.

I would suggest having a look at these videos on youtube: [simple explanation of neural networks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNqc4fkdfIo&list=UUR1-GEpyOPzT2AO4D_eifdw&index=14&feature=plpp_video)

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In this problem, we are trying to learn the NAND function. And therefore the **input vector** is `(a,b,a NAND b)` and the **desired output** is whether this input combination is correct or wrong, i-e whether it is a correct representation of NAND function.

For example `((1,1,1), 0)` means `1 NAND 1 = 1` is wrong and therefore it is classified as 0(Wrong). `((1,1,0), 1)` means `1 NAND 1 = 0` is correct and therefore it is classified as 1(Correct).

And as other combinations are added as part of training data then the classifier will learn NAND function. Following are a few more tuples that can be added to training data.

```
((0,0,1),1)
((0,1,1),1)
((1,0,1),1)
((0,0,0),0)
((0,1,0),0)
((1,0,0),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is in Java, I am just getting into Python so I will update this answer when I get around to it.

```java
boolean nand(boolean[] a) {
  boolean b = true
  if (a.length > 1) {
    b = a[0] && a[1];
    if (a.length > 2)
      for (int i = 2; i < a.length; i++)
        b &= a[i];
  }
  return !b;
}
```

Usage (Should return true):

```
nand(training_set[i][0]) == training_set[i][1]
```

## Edit

Over two years later, I have come back to this question to add to my answer...

I have created an iterative and recursive solution in python. I have also attempted to code golf the recursive. I got it down to 106 bytes.

### Implementations

#### Iterative

```py
def nand(*a):
    if len(a) > 1:
        b = a[0] and a[1]
        if len(a) > 2:
            for i in range(2, len(a)):
                b = b and a[i]
        return not b
    return None
```

#### Recursive

```py
def nand(*a):
    if len(a) < 2:
        return None
    elif len(a) == 2:
        return not (a[0] and a[1])
    else:
        return nand(*([a[0] and a[1]] + list(a[2:])))
```

#### Recursive (lambda)

```py
nand=lambda*a:None if len(a)<2 else not(a[0]and a[1])if len(a)==2 else nand(*([a[0]and a[1]]+list(a[2:])))
```

### Results

```py
print nand(True,  True,  True)   #  ¬(1 ∧ 1 ∧ 1) == 0
print nand(True,  True,  False)  #  ¬(1 ∧ 1 ∧ 0) == 1
print nand(True,  False, True)   #  ¬(1 ∧ 0 ∧ 1) == 1
print nand(True,  False, False)  #  ¬(1 ∧ 0 ∧ 0) == 1
print nand(False, True,  True)   #  ¬(0 ∧ 1 ∧ 1) == 1
print nand(False, True,  False)  #  ¬(0 ∧ 1 ∧ 0) == 1
print nand(False, False, True)   #  ¬(0 ∧ 0 ∧ 1) == 1
print nand(False, False, False)  #  ¬(0 ∧ 0 ∧ 0) == 1
```

Answer (score -1):

NAND can take as many arguments as you would like.  Simply AND all of the input values together and negate the output.

```
// 2 arguments
!(A & B)

// 3 arguments
!(A & B & C)

// n argument
!(A & B & ... & n)
```